# 2 sets of independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have a question which is confusing me and I can't seem to prove it:
If $A$ and $B$ are independent events and $C$ and $D$ are independent events then are $(A \cup C)$ and $(B \cup D)$ independent events?

Help would be appreciated

Comment: What if $A=D$ and $B=C$?

Comment: For both cases, being equal and not being equal

Comment: @ ZDD you seem to be missing @carmichael561's point.  Let me rephrase it then so it is more obvious... if $A$ and $B$ are independent events as well as $B$ and $A$ are independent events, then are $(A\cup B)$ and $(B\cup A)$ independent events?

Comment: It is certainly possible that the respective unions are independent, but it is not guaranteed.  Do you see why it is not guaranteed having looked at the earlier comments?  What is more difficult to prove is that it is possible for them to be independent... but another trivial example will show that (*e.g. if $A=B=C=D=\Omega$ where $\Omega$ represents the entire sample space*)